# For Each Skip Current and Move to Next VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a For Each statement that checks a number of directories and calls a function that checks for folder consistency (folder name etc.).

The function returns true if it finds an error, what would be the best solution if the Boolean is return as True to continue the next 'row' in the For Each statement?

Is it best to use an `On Error GoTo <Label>` and then do a 'Resume' Call at the 'Next'?

I'm trying to cut down a program from A LOT of unused code which I'm doing successfully and wish to do this in compact way that doesn't compromise the for each process.

Comment: No, just use "Continue For".  Please dont ever use On Error Resume Next in a .NET application.

Comment: Sometimes you can skip the operation inside a For by using an IF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Continue For to break out and continue the For Loop, not a Go To.

```
If condition Then
   Continue For
End If
```

Go To and Resume are ideas that carry over from Procedural coding, in .NET you can cut out the need for these confusing logic blocks using function calls, and an object oriented design approach.

Utilize Try-Catch if you know that you can handle a given exception and continue execution.

Comment: Thank You DavidY exactly what I was looking for.